# Dataannotations for list in blazor page

Tags: validation, asp.net-core, data-annotations, blazor, blazor-server-side

I use the following to do validations on a form in blazor(server)

```
<EditForm Model="@place" OnValidSubmit="HandleValidSubmit" Context="placesEdit" >
<DataAnnotationsValidator />
 <InputText @bind-Value="place.Name"/>
<ValidationMessage For="() => place.Name" />
</EditForm>
@{place=new Place(); }
```

the property `Name` as a `[required]` - Attribute. *This works fine*. When submitting the form I see the error message and the `HandleValidSubmit` isn't called

But when I try to do the same with a List the validation isn't happening. No error is displayed and `HandleValidSubmit` is called instead even if the requirements are not met:

```
<EditForm Model="@places" OnValidSubmit="HandleValidSubmit" Context="placesEdit" >
<DataAnnotationsValidator />
 @foreach(var place in places) {
   <InputText @bind-Value="place.Name"/>
   <ValidationMessage For="() => place.Name" />
}
</EditForm>
@{places=new List<Place>(); }
```

What has do be done that the Validator also works in the loop?

Answer (score 4):

Try if this helps:

1. Add the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.DataAnnotations.Validation` NuGet package.

   - This is a pre-release package and latest version is 3.2.0-rc1.20223.4. There is a plan to include this on the native Blazor SDK but that version should work up to .NET 5. https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/22238#issuecomment-634266426
2. Replace your `DataAnnotationsValidator` with `ObjectGraphDataAnnotationsValidator`

   - You can check if your issue gets resolved with Step 2. If not, continue to Step 3.
3. Annotate your list property with `ValidateComplexType`.

   - You will need to create a class that will contain your list property.

check the docs for more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms-validation#nested-models-collection-types-and-complex-types

---

If you're using `IValidatableObject` like me, the above solution won't work. The workaround is to create another property to link the validation into.

e.g.

```cs
public class MyModel : IValidatableObject
{
    public List<Place> Places { get; } = new List<Place>();
    public object PlacesValidation { get; }
    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var isValid = ...;
        if (isValid)
            yield return new ValidationResult("Places is invalid.", new[] { nameof(PlacesValidation ) });
    }
}
```

```html
<ValidationMessage For="() => Model.PlacesValidation"/>
```